# Why does this two NOT circuit oscillate?

Tags: oscillator

I built the following circuit and it oscillates at about 1 Hz. I can't figure out however how it works. I picked the design up from an old Bernard Babani book (1979) on 7400 series ICs. The book doesn't explain how it works either. The book uses a 7400 to supply the NOT gates (combining two NAND gate inputs to form a NOT gate). I don't do that, instead I have a transitor based circuit that behaves as a NOT gate. However it oscillates as the book suggested it would. I implemented the circuit in circuitlab and I can get the simulation to show square wave oscillations, see below.

[image]

Simulation from circuitlab

[image]

Comment: *I havn't tried simulating it on CircuitLab yet* - Try it then.

Comment: I will, but from your comment I presume you don't know how it works either?

Comment: We encourage to exhaust the own research capabilities before asking a question. You haven't done with yours yet.

Comment: I tried to simulate it on circuitlab but it would take almost three hours to simulate 1 second of model time. See if I can do something about that.

Comment: I'd like to add that I've done a lot of reasearch on this problem. Most of the gate oscillators I understand including the negative feedback and relaxation oscillators. This one has stumped me. If stackoverflow can't help I'll talk to an electrical engineer at the local university.

Comment: I tried again with circuitlab, reduced the time to a much smaller end point, this time it crashed. I did a dc static simulation, *all* nodes are at 5 volts. Don't think this helps.

Comment: It won't oscillate for ideal components. Try redrawing the gates with some finite input impedance.

Comment: The circuit oscillates because it has positive feedback. What is the problem?

Comment: Ali Chen: Perhaps you could enlighten us by identifying where the positive feedback is. Note that two NOT gates connected like this without capacitors will not oscillate. My take is this. 

Assume all capacitors are initially discharged. Assume the output of A is high, this charges the capacitor next to it which slowly raises the voltage to the point where gate B flips from high to low, this does not cause the second capacitor to charge which keeps the input at gate A low. In order words we've returned to exactly the same state, no oscillation. Have I got the capacitor charging wrong?

Comment: Between the input and the ground.

Comment: ok I'll try it.

Comment: Eugene: That didn't help but when I put a 10/100K resistor around each gate then it did oscillate. I see if I can figure out why it oscillates.

Comment: Change again, turns out the resistors weren't important, I took the resistors out and it still oscillated. Perhaps I had an invisible break somwhere than prevented a time course simulation. The original problem remains however, why does it oscillate. And no comments like 'because it has a positivefeedback. Let's be cosntructive, please provide more information, eg where is the positive feedback or better still a walk through of the events that result in an oscillation.

Comment: I think I figured it out, its very subtle, not at all obvious. Thanks for the advice, more research did infact succeed. It's not a circuit we commonly see today so the books don't tend to mention it.

Comment: @ rody  Using bipolars, with base resistors, this is the classic astable oscillator. See Figure 1 on this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivibrator

Comment: Did you learn more by nutting it out yourself, or being spoon-fed the answer? The question needs an answer. You're now in a position to post your own reply, that's permitted and indeed encouraged on this site. Don't forget to draw the parallel with multivibrator above. Will this circuit work with other logic gate families? I am an engineer with 40y experience, and while I know the multivibrator circuit well, it had not occurred to me to use TTL NOTs for the transistors, so I've learnt something from your question as well, +1.

Comment: Neil_UK: Yes I learned lots more by figuring it out myself, In total I probably spent 6 to 12 hours studying, 6 before I asked the question and another 6 afterwards. I didn't find any explanation on the internet (and I searched....) but instead I found a detailed explanation in an obscure 60s article at the library. I am familiar with astable oscillators but the details of the one I posted had some subtle implemenation issues which I struggled with. I knew it was a long shot to ask stackoverflow as it's is a bit of an obscure implementation.

Comment: In summary, the best answer I got was do my own research and that's the advice I will give in response to my own question. I could give the answer in all its gory detail, but in the long run it’s better to figure it out yourself although it might take some time. The comparison with a transistor multivibrator turns out to a red herring. True in the big picture the feedback pattern is similar but the implementation is different. Note there are no explicit resistors in the circuit diagram.

Comment: analogsystemsrf. Thanks for the reply, I did know that the circuit was an astable oscillator (I should have been clearer in the question). However the Wikipedia article on the multivibrator, which I am aware or, doesn't help in this case. It gives a bird's eye view of the concept with the classic transistor mutlivibrator as a specific case. An explanation in terms of the actual implementation I posted is what I was after. This is why I asked the question, but no one seems to know. However I figured it out in the end.

Answer (score 3):

This circuit is a variant of so-called ["astable multivibrator", see Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivibrator).

> An astable multivibrator consists of two amplifying stages connected
>   in a positive feedback loop by two capacitive-resistive coupling
>   networks.The amplifying elements may be
>   junction or field-effect transistors, vacuum tubes, operational
>   amplifiers, or other types of amplifier.

Two inverters form a non-inverting amplifier, so the feedback loop is positive. Timing for flip-flops is determined by capacitors values times some input impedance (or current, for TTL).

CLARIFICATION: The TTL inverters have essentially DC floating inputs in this circuit. Initially, parasitic leakages move the input voltages up crossing the switching threshold area, so the gates essentially enter the linear amplifier regime. The rest happens similar to the ordinary BJT multivibrator, initial state is based on realistic differences in element parameters, and then the switch frequency is determined by discharges of caps into input impedance of the circuit.

Comment: Its more complex that you make out. It is true that two inverters in a cycle will have two stable states, 10 and 01. Its only the with the capacitors that makes the state unstable. I'm 90% certain that what we have then is a relaxation oscillator.  Thankfully I found a much fuller explanation in an obscure article.

Comment: @rhody, young man, which part of "...feedback loop by **capacitive-resistive** coupling network..." did you miss?

Comment: Capacitive-resistance coupling is a generic statement, it just sugegsts transfer of energy, doesn't explain what is going on in a specific case. I found an explanation in an article from the 60s. You might be unsure of the details of this circuit, you would have given it if you did. I am sure you know the big picture. The quote you give is a prelude to the transistor multivibrator (TM) which is not in detail how my circuit works. I understand the TM perfectly but the one I gave is more subtle. True there are capacitors and feedbacks but the details differ. This is WHY I posted the question.

Comment: @AliChen  74xx series TTL has pull-ups on the inputs, not floating.

Comment: @Jasen, no, original TTL did NOT have any pull-ups, please check their actual schematics diagrams, e.g. https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/worksheets/ttl-logic-gates/#24 or go straight to Texas Instruments pages. Maybe some modern series do, I am not sure, but it does not change the basic idea.

Comment: @Ali Chen https://www.unicornelectronics.com/ftp/Data%20Sheets/7400.pdf page 3, (it seems `ti` has dropped the schematic from its most recent data sheet)   there is sufficient pull up there to achieve an unambigous TTL  logic high (which is less than 2 volts)